# How to properly create a new trace with micrometer and spring boot 3

Tags: java, micrometer, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

In some rare cases, I have to create a completely new trace, separate from any parent TraceContext or ObservationContext.

An example : I could have an api that starts the processing of 100 items, and let's say that for each of these items there will be feign calls, spring cloud stream hops, etc...
Spring will automatically creates an ObservationContext from the api, so I will have the same trace for the api call and all the processing for each of these items. I'm using kibana, If I find an error log and filters on the traceId I get all the items, it's almost the same as no correlation at all, there are too many lines. I can't correlate on the spanId either, new spans are created all the time !

So in some specific and controlled cases I want to start a new trace for each of these items : I know I will loose the correlation with the api call, but that's OK.

I've played quite extensively with the ObservationRegistry, the ContextSnapshot, etc... but can't get it to working. The code always finds a way to find the parent ObservationContext of TracingContext.

Ideally I'd like to

- backup the current trace context
- create a new trace context from scratch
- execute some code with that new trace context
- restore the former trace context

This could be done quite easily before (with sleuth) ... but now it's a head scratcher :smile:

I don't know if this helps but I'm looking for the `runWithNewTrace` method that would be used this way :

```java
List<String> traceIds = new ArrayList<>();

Observation.createNotStarted("test.traceObservation", observationRegistry) // 1
        .contextualName("create test with Observation API") // 2
        .observe(() -> {
            traceIds.add(getCurrentTraceId());
            runWithNewTrace("test", () -> traceIds.add(getCurrentTraceId()));
            traceIds.add(getCurrentTraceId());
        });

String traceIdBefore = traceIds.get(0);
String traceIdThatShouldBeDifferent = traceIds.get(1);
String traceIdAfterThatShouldBeSameAsBefore = traceIds.get(2);

assertThat(traceIdThatShouldBeDifferent).isNotNull().isNotEqualTo("no-trace");
assertThat(traceIdBefore).isNotEqualTo(traceIdThatShouldBeDifferent);
assertThat(traceIdBefore).isEqualTo(traceIdAfterThatShouldBeSameAsBefore);
```

getTraceId looks like this :

```java
public String getCurrentTraceId() {
    Span currentSpan = tracer.currentSpan();
    if (currentSpan != null && currentSpan.context() != null) {
        return currentSpan.context().traceId();
    }
    return "no-trace";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Got the answer from Marcin Grzejszczak : you have to use a NullObservation to clear all the thread stuff and create a new observation from there :

```
new NullObservation(observationRegistry)
        .observe(() -> Observation.start(name, observationRegistry)
                           .observe(() -> {
                               // code to execute with a new observation
                           }));
```