Tracing context is not propagated when using a CompletableFuture
The following test is not working as it should
@Test
void testContextPropagation() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    // create a new trace using the micrometer tracer coming from the Spring Boot context
    ScopedSpan scopedSpan = tracer.startScopedSpan("trigger the creation of a new trace...");
    logger.info("CONTEXT: {}", tracer.currentTraceContext().context());
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        logger.info("CONTEXT: {}", tracer.currentTraceContext().context());
        return null;
    }, ContextSnapshotFactory.builder().build().captureAll().wrapExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())).get();
    scopedSpan.end();
}

The ouptut of this test will be
CONTEXT: 661e6f0f5965abb6cb8ddf9d107eea2c/cb8ddf9d107eea2c
CONTEXT: null

while it should be
CONTEXT: 661e6f0f5965abb6cb8ddf9d107eea2c/cb8ddf9d107eea2c
CONTEXT: 661e6f0f5965abb6cb8ddf9d107eea2c/cb8ddf9d107eea2c

The expected behaviour would be to keep the trace context into the CompletableFuture but this is not the case.
Spring Boot version: 3.2.4
Any help on that topic is more than welcome. The Spring Boot and micrometer documentation around tracing is quite poor. Did I misunderstand something?
The idea would be to keep the tracing context to allow forwarding it to the next layers, including baggages...

Using the proposal made in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77090898/how-to-properly-create-a-new-trace-with-micrometer-and-spring-boot-3 to create the new trace instead of using the tracer is fixing the issue but this is so unclear which method needs to be used to address such kind of scenario. So, any help is still more than welcome.

You can use ContextExecutorService (or ContextScheduledExecutorService) to automatically propagate tracing information using CompletableFuture but you need to pass that executor to CompletableFuture (see its javadoc):
ContextExecutorService.wrap(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

and you might need to register an accessor:
ContextRegistry.getInstance().registerThreadLocalAccessor(...);

If you cannot do this for some reason, you need to do it manually, see this issue: context-propagation#138 or check one of our tests that does this: CurrentObservationTest:
@Test
void testManualContextPropagation() throws Exception {
    Span newSpan = this.tracer.nextSpan().name("test").start();
    try (SpanInScope ignored = this.tracer.withSpan(newSpan)) {
        System.out.println("CONTEXT: " + tracer.currentSpan().context());
    }
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try (SpanInScope ignored = this.tracer.withSpan(newSpan)) {
            System.out.println("CONTEXT: " + tracer.currentSpan().context());
        }
        finally {
            newSpan.end();
        }
    }).get();
}

